# Calling list.index(a) results in attribute call, not method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, python-3.5

I've been trying to create a script that takes lists inside a dictionary, and edits them to create a grid-like thing. I'm trying to make a variable equivalent to the index of a value in the list, but the error says there is no such attribute in the data. I'm trying to call the METHOD, not retrive an attribute, but that's what the machine thinks I want to do.

I'm using the 32-bit version of Python 3.5.

Here's the script. I've added a comment to the line in question.

```
#Map Generation Script
GRID = {
1 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
2 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
3 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
4 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
5 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
6 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
7 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
8 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
9 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
10 : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
}

def usepen(x):
Areaedit = GRID[godpenx]
Areaedit[godpeny] = x
GRID[godpenx] = Areaedit

def makeshapeline(tile, length):
for item in GRID:               #I know this isn't indented properly
    for unit in GRID[item]:
        if unit == tile:
            locpenx = GRID.index(item) #offending line
            locpeny = GRID[item].index(tile) 
            anglea = randrange(0,1)
            angleb = randrange(0,1)
            while anglea + angleb == 0:
                anglea = randrange(0,1)
                angleb = randrange(0,1)
            for nump in length:
                locpenx += anglea
                locpeny += angleb
                if locpenx or locpeny > 9:
                    break
                GRID[locpenx[locpeny]] = tile

usepen(0)
makeshapeline(0, randrange(1,8))
for item in GRID:
    print (GRID[item])
```

Comment: Note that a method call is really just getting and then calling a callable attribute, with some fun instance binding stuff. If you get an `AttributeError`, then you're trying to call `index` on **something that isn't a list**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `locpenx = GRID.index(item)` is the offending line :

You need to have something like this -

```
locpenx = GRID[1].index(item)
```

or

```
locpenx = GRID[2].index(item)
```

.. and so on.